# Access Synology logs from Java application

Tags: java, synology

I have a Synology NAS disk and I want to access the logs that exist in the [Log Center](https://kb.synology.com/en-us/DSM/help/DSM/LogCenter/logcenter_desc?version=7) from a Java application. I checked [Synology API](https://global.download.synology.com/download/Document/Software/DeveloperGuide/Package/FileStation/All/enu/Synology_File_Station_API_Guide.pdf) and there isn't any GET query for this and I haven't found a way to access the logs.

Can you suggest a way to accomplish that?